# Accumulated count for each element in a range

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a table x, where start and end are hour of the day.

`x = data.table(start=c(5,7,9,12), end=c(12,14,15,20), val = 7:10)`

I want the output table to be:

for each hour from  hour 4 (not 5) to the 21 (not 20), has the accumulated value such as:

```
hour total
4    0
5    7
6    7
7    15(7+8)
```

Comment: I don't understand neither your question nor your example.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the OP question is that each row in the input dataset `x` is a segment with start and an end. We need to compute for each value in the total interval the sum of the values corresponding to the segments in which the hour is included.

One possible solution with `dplyr`/`purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
## Create the data 
x = data.frame(start=c(5,7,9,12), end=c(12,14,15,20), val = as.double(7:10))
## Extract possible values
values <- seq(from=min(x$start), to=max(x$end))
## Function for one given hour
cumval <- function(hour){
    tibble(
        hour=hour, 
        total = x %>% mutate(tot=if_else( (hour>=start & hour<=end), val, 0)) %>% 
        pull(tot) %>% sum
        )
}
## Iterate
values %>% purrr::map_dfr(cumval)
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 2
    hour total
   <int> <dbl>
 1     5     7
 2     6     7
 3     7    15
 4     8    15
 5     9    24
 6    10    24
 7    11    24
 8    12    34
 9    13    27
10    14    27
11    15    19
12    16    10
13    17    10
14    18    10
15    19    10
16    20    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple base R solution:

```
hour  <- min(x$start):max(x$end)
total <- sapply(hour, function(i) sum(x$val[x$start <= i & x$end >= i])))
data.frame(hour, total)
#>    hour total
#> 1     5     7
#> 2     6     7
#> 3     7    15
#> 4     8    15
#> 5     9    24
#> 6    10    24
#> 7    11    24
#> 8    12    34
#> 9    13    27
#> 10   14    27
#> 11   15    19
#> 12   16    10
#> 13   17    10
#> 14   18    10
#> 15   19    10
#> 16   20    10
```

Comment: Simpler than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `data.table` option using `by=.EACHI` for each hour:

```
x[.(hr=max(0L, min(x)-1L):min(23L, max(end)+1L)),
    on=.(start<=hr, end>=hr), by=.EACHI, fcoalesce(sum(val), 0L)]
```

output:

```
    start end V1
 1:     4   4  0
 2:     5   5  7
 3:     6   6  7
 4:     7   7 15
 5:     8   8 15
 6:     9   9 24
 7:    10  10 24
 8:    11  11 24
 9:    12  12 34
10:    13  13 27
11:    14  14 27
12:    15  15 19
13:    16  16 10
14:    17  17 10
15:    18  18 10
16:    19  19 10
17:    20  20 10
18:    21  21  0
```